# How to append a method call to a builder-like chain of calls using Expression?

Tags: c#

I have a method that looks like this:

```cs
public Builder Source(Builder builder) {
  return builder
         .DoX()
         .DoY();
}
```

I need to append this method with another Builder call so that final Expression would look like this:

```cs
public Builder Source(Builder builder) {
  return builder
         .DoX()
         .DoY()
         .DoZ();
}
```

Is this even achievable in modern C#?

EDIT: Okay, I clearly didn't emphasize enough on using Expressions.
I found the solution myself and here is what I was talking about:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ExpressionTest
{
    class Builder
    {
        public Builder DoX()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public Builder DoY()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public Builder DoZ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did Z");
            return this;
        }
    }

    static class Test
    {
        public static Builder Source(Builder builder)
        {
            return builder.DoX().DoY();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<Builder, Builder> func = Test.Source;
            Expression<Func<Builder, Builder>> expr = b => func(b);

            var doZMethod = typeof(Builder).GetMethod("DoZ");
            var builderParam = expr.Parameters[0];
            var assignExpr = Expression.Assign(builderParam, expr.Body);
            var callZ = Expression.Call(builderParam, doZMethod ?? throw new ApplicationException());

            var block = Expression.Block(
                assignExpr,
                callZ
            );

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Builder, Builder>>(block, builderParam);
            var funcWithDoZ = lambda.Compile();

            Console.WriteLine("Invoking rebuild expression...");
            funcWithDoZ.Invoke(new Builder());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Builder`? If all its "Do" methods `return this;` then chaining should be trivial. What exactly is the issue you have with the code?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Roman.Pavelko, your `Do` methods should have return type of `Builder` and return `this`.

Just as an additional thing; sometimes you might want to restrict what operations are available at any point in the chain. To achieve this, you can have multiple interfaces (implemented by the `Builder` class) where each defines the operations that are available e.g.

```cs
   public interface IBuilderY
   {
      IBuilderZ DoY();
   }

   public interface IBuilderZ
   {
      void DoZ();
   }

   public class Builder : IBuilderY, IBuilderZ
   {

      public IBuilderY DoX()
      {
         return this;
      }

      public IBuilderZ DoY()
      {
         return this;
      }

      public void DoZ()
      {

      }
   }
```

in this example I can do `builder.DoX().DoY().DoZ()`, but not `builder.DoX().DoZ()`. Might not be required for your scenario, but handy to know...

Answer (score 0):

Add `DoZ()` method in your `Builder` class that returns `this`:

```
public class Builder
{
    public Builder DoZ()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```